# display python script output in a web page [server running flask]

Tags: python, azure, flask, flask-restful

I'm running flask on an Azure server and send data from a form using POST, as an argument to a python script.

Here's how I pass the argument to the script and run it

```
os.system("python3 script.py " + postArgument)
```

The output is displayed normally in the logs as it would on a terminal.

**How do I get the output back onto the new web page?**

Comment: Why can't you import this script and run it? You don't need to use OS commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pipe , Here is how it is done

```
os.popen("python3 script.py " + postArgument).read()
```

From security perspective i would suggest you do some sanity check on the `postArguements` before using

**EDIT:answering comment asking why sanity check**

The code is vulnurable to *command injection*

> Command injection is an attack in which the goal is execution of
>   arbitrary commands on the host operating system via a vulnerable
>   application. Command injection attacks are possible when an
>   application passes unsafe user supplied data (forms, cookies, HTTP
>   headers etc.) to a system shell. In this attack, the attacker-supplied
>   operating system commands are usually executed with the privileges of
>   the vulnerable application. Command injection attacks are possible
>   largely due to insufficient input validation.

Let me try to demonstrate a possibile attack in your case
if

```
postArgument = "blah ; rm -rf /"
```

then

```
os.popen("python3 script.py " + postArgument).read()
```

will be equalent to

```
os.popen("python3 script.py blah ; rm -rf /").read()
```

This will try to remove all the files in the systems .

How to avoid this
Either use `pipes.Quote`

```
import pipes
p = os.popen("python3 script.py " + pipes.quote(postArgument)).read()
```

or use `subprocess`,this is recomended since `os.popen` is depricated

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "script.py", postArguemnt])
```

Read [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection) about command injection

Comment: Could you explain the "sanity check" you're talking about?

Comment: read about command injection here https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_Injection

Comment: @KalolParty i have updated the answer with details on sanity check . Please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: Thanks! Good stuff!

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid this? Also, it runs on my local server but not on my azure server.